# how can i set 'n' no of inputs value in an array state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z82bf.png)

the picture shows my dynamic form where I don't know how many question will come on every single box and on every **NEXT** I want to call an API for saving data but I am confused how can I set array of state for payload like this
array = [
{
id:1,
values:[{question:'which is on form',answer:'what user enter'}]

},
{
id:2,
values:[{question:'which is on form',answer:'what user enter'}]

},
.
.
.
.
.
.
till no of questions is present in single box form
]
I am using onChange method and pushing the values on state but it didn't work thanks in advance.
piece of code where I am rendering the question

```
 <div>
                    {card.data?.map((item, key) => {
                      // console.log("item.question", item.question);
                      return (
                        <div htmlFor="" className="my-2 d-flex" key={item.id}>
                          <div key={item.id}>{item.question}</div>
                          <div>
                            <Input
                              id={item.id}
                              size="medium"
                              placeholder=""
                              onChange={(e) =>
                                handleChanges(
                                  e,
                                  item.question,
                                  e.target.value,
                                  item.id
                                )
                              }
                            />
                          </div>{" "}
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What does your handleChanges function do?

Comment: firstly I push the value in an array but it didn't work so it is just loging the input and question value

Comment: I think you need to show us what you did. With the snippets you added we can't help you.